# Open second Fragment from first fragment issue

Tags: xml, android-fragments, fragment

I added a button on my first fragment and that lead to my second fragment (fragment 2). Initially it was working, then after I added images on my second fragment but it showed an error and did not open.

I wrote this code which suddenly got an error:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This code initially worked but suddenly it stopped working after I added images etc.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: "it showed an error": what did it say?

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. "It showed an error", "got an error", and "it stopped working", provide no information for anyone to help you.